# What does the error "binding const string to to reference of type x" mean?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class CEntry{
public:
    CEntry();
    ~CEntry(){}
    string& getSymbol() const;
    void setSymbol(string a);
private:
    string m_symbol;
};

CEntry::CEntry():
    m_symbol("")
    {}

string& CEntry::getSymbol() const{
    return m_symbol; //this is where the error occurs
}

void CEntry::setSymbol(string a){
    m_symbol = a;
}

int main(){return 0;}
```

I am trying to return a reference to CEntry's private member variable `m_symbol`, and I can't quite wrap my head around what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please don't use `<string.h>`. The `<string>` header is what you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

You have (rightly) declared your `getSymbol()` member function as `const` – which means that it cannot modify any data members of the class. Thus, in the scope of that function, `m_symbol` is a `const string`.

However, the function itself returns a (non-const) reference, which would allow any calling function to modify the referred-to data member. This is not allowed.

To fix the issue, you can simply use the 'conventional' approach (for getters), and declare the return type of the `getSymbol()` function to be a `const` reference:

```cpp
const string& CEntry::getSymbol() const
{
    return m_symbol;
}
```

(Note that you'll also need to add the leading `const` to the in-class *declaration*.)

With this, any (direct) attempt to modify the `m_symbol` member using the reference returned by `getSymbol()` will fail; thus, the compiler is now satisfied that all references to `const` data are consistent.

Comment: Note that `string const& getSymbol() const` and `const string& getSymbol() const` are equivalent - you can even use one for the declaration and the other for the definition.

Comment: @AnimorRomina If this answer (or the other one) solved your problem, you can go ahead and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getSymbol` is `const`-qualified, all the member variables are *also* `const`-qualified within the scope of that member function.  Your options are:

- remove the `const` qualification
- change the return type to `string const&` (this is probably what you want)